# flex and bison: parse string without quotes

Tags: c++, string, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I'm working on a mgf file parser (syntax: http://www.matrixscience.com/help/data_file_help.html) using flex + bison c + +.

I've realized the lexer (lex) and parser (yacc). But I've a problem that I can't solve : when I try to parse strings.

Important : there is no ' or " around the string.

Here is an example of input:

```
CHARGE=1+, 2+ and 3+
#some comments

BEGIN IONS
TITLE= Cmpd 1, +MSn(417.2108), 10.0 min  //line 20
PEPMASS=417.21083   35173
CHARGE=3+
123.79550   20  
285.16455   56  
302.14335   146 1+
[other datas ...]
END IONS

BEGIN IONS
[an other one ... ]
```

Here the (minimal) lexer:
MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG is juste a macro to print a line

```
#define MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG(val) std::cout<<"token: "<<val<<std::endl

\n {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("T_EOL");
    return token::T_EOL;
}

^[#;!/][^\n]* {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("T_COMMENT");
    return token::T_COMMENT;
}

[[:space:]] {}

/** values **/
[0-9]+ {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("V_INTEGER"<<" (="<<yytext<<")");
    return token::V_INTEGER;
}

[0-9]+"."[0-9]* {
   MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("V_DOUBLE"<<" (="<<yytext<<")");
   return token::V_DOUBLE;
}

[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?[eE][+-][0-9]+ {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("V_DOUBLE"<<" (="<<yytext<<")");
    return token::V_DOUBLE;
}

"+" {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("T_PLUS");
    return token::T_PLUS;
}


"=" {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("T_EQUALS");
    return token::T_EQUALS;
}

"," {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("T_COMA");
    return token::T_COMA;
}

"and" {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("T_AND");
    return token::T_AND;
}
/*** keywords */
^"CHARGE" {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("K_CHARGE");
    return token::K_CHARGE;
}

^"TITLE" {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("K_TITLE");
    return token::K_TITLE;
}
[ others keywords ...]

/**** string : problem here **/
[A-Za-z]([:;,()A-Za-z0-9_.-]|[[:space]])* {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("V_STRING"<<" (="<<yytext<<")");
    return token::V_STRING;
}
```

And the (minimized) parser.

```
start : headerparams blocks T_END;

headerparams : /* empty */| headerparams headerparam;

headerparam : K_CHARGE T_EQUALS charge_list T_EOL | [others ...];

blocks : /* empty */ | blocks block;

block : T_BEGIN_IONS T_EOL blockparams ions T_END_IONS T_EOL| T_BEGIN_IONS T_EOL blockparams T_END_IONS T_EOL;

blockparam  : K_CHARGE T_EQUALS charge T_EOL | K_TITLE T_EQUALS V_STRING T_EOL | [others...];

ion : number number  T_EOL| number number charge T_EOL;

ions : ions ion| ion;

number : V_INTEGER | V_DOUBLE;

charge : V_INTEGER T_PLUS | V_INTEGER T_MINUS;

charge_list : charge| charge_list T_COMA charge | charge_list T_AND charge;
```

My problem is that I get the next token:

```
[...]
[line 20]
token: K_TITLE
token: T_EQUALS
token: v_STRING (= Cmpd)
token: V_INTEGER (= 1)
Error line 20: syntax error, unexpected integer, expecting end of line
```

I would like to have:

```
[...]
[line 20]
token: K_TITLE
token: T_EQUALS
token: v_STRING (Cmpd 1, +MSn (417.2108), 10.0 min)
token: T_EOL
```

If someone can help me ...

---

Edit #1
I've "solve" the problem using the concatenation of tokens:

lex:

```
[A-Za-z][^\n[:space:]+-=,]* {
    MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("V_STRING"<<" (="<<yytext<<")"))
    return token::V_STRING;t
}
```

yacc:

```
   string_st : V_STRING
      | string_st V_STRING
      | string_st number
      | string_st T_COMA
      | string_st T_PLUS
      | string_st T_MINUS
      ;

blockparam  : K_CHARGE T_EQUALS charge T_EOL | K_TITLE T_EQUALS string_st T_EOL | [others...];
```

Comment: The appropriate tag is `flex-lexer`, as `flex` is something Adobe related.

Answer (score 1):

if your string will alway start with some text `TITLE` and end with some text `\n` (new line char)
I would suggest you to use [start conditions](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_11.html),

```
%x IN_TITLE

"TITLE"        { /* return V_STRING of TITILE in c++ code */ BEGIN(IN_TITLE); }
<IN_TITLE>=    { /* return T_EQUALS in c++ code */; }
<IN_TITLE>"\n" { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
<IN_TITLE>.*   { MGF_TOKEN_DEBUG("V_STRING"<<" (="<<yytext<<")");return token::V_STRING; }
```

%x `IN_TITLE` defines the `IN_TITLE` state, and the pattern text `TITLE` will make it start. Once it's started, `\n` will have it go back to the initial state (INITIAL is predefined), and every other characters will just be consumed to `V_STRING` without any particular action.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is a simple typo:

```
[A-Za-z]([:;,()A-Za-z0-9_.-]|[[:space]])*
```

should be:

```
[A-Za-z]([:;,()A-Za-z0-9_.-]|[[:space:]])*
                                     ^
```

You don't actually need the `|` operator. The following is perfectly legal (but probably not what you want either; see below):

```
[A-Za-z][[:space:]:;,()A-Za-z0-9_.-]*
```

---

Once you fix that, you'll find that you have another problem: your keywords (`TITLE`, for example) will be lexed as `STRING` because the `STRING` pattern is longer. (In fact, since `[:space:]` includes `\n`, the `STRING` pattern will probably extend to the end of the input. You probably wanted `[:blank:]`.)

I took a quick glance at the description of the format you're trying to parse, but it's not a very precise description. But it appears that parameter lines have the format:

```
^[[:alpha:]]+=.*$
```

Perhaps the `:alpha:` should be `:alnum:` or even something more permissive; as I said, the description wasn't very precise. What was clear is that:

- The keyword is case-insensitive, so both `TITLE` and `title` will work identically, and
- The `=` sign is obligatory and may not have a space on either side of it. (So your `TITLE=` line is not correct, but maybe it doesn't matter).

In order to not interfere with parsing of the data, you might want to make the above a single "token" whose value is the part after the `=` and whose type corresponds to the (case-normalized) keyword. Of course, each parameter-type may require an idiosyncratic value parser, which could only be achieved in `flex` by use of start conditions. In any event, you should think about the consequences of stray characters in the `TITLE` which are not part of the `STRING` pattern, and how you propose to deal with the resulting lexical error.

---

Your code does not make it clear how you communicate text values from your lexer to your parser. You need to be aware that the value of `yytext` is only safe inside of the lexer action for the token it corresponds to. The next call to the lexer will invalidate it, and bison parsers almost always have a lookahead token, so the lexer will have been called again before the token is processed. Consequently, you *must* copy `yytext` in order to pass it to the parser, and the parser needs to take ownership of the copy so that you don't end up leaking memory.